# Difference between Openstack compute, Openstack server, Openstack ironic, Openstack hosts?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am getting confused about how all these terms are defined.
Each has a separate commands list also.

Commands:
compute agent
compute agent create
compute agent delete
compute agent list
compute agent set
compute service
compute service delete
compute service list
compute service set

server add fixed ip
server add floating ip
server add port
server add security group
server add volume
server create
server delete
server dump create
server list

host list
host set
host show

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Openstack compute refers to compute service (=nova  multiple services - api,conductor,compute)).

Host list refers to your controllers and computes added to your cloud.
Hypervisor list would list your Computes.

Openstack server list refers to instances (VMs) running in your cloud. For info, this is role based. So if your were the admin, you'd only see servers in the admin project. If you wanted (as admin) to see servers in all projects, you would need to use openstack server list --all-tenants.